# Faltou atualizar a lista de moderadores do chat?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, chat, moderação

Não se é convenção (ou obrigação), mas desde que participo do site os próprios moderadores da comunidade que moderavam também no chat.

Se assim for, faltou atualizar a lista de moderadores do chat?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O utluiz ainda consta como moderador do chat, enquanto o Bacco não foi adicionado.

Comment: Eu não chamaria de bug, e não sei como mudar isto ou se precisa. Alias se for pra fazer tem mais gente que na prática não modera mais nada no site e podemos dizer que é oficial :) E faltava um moderador que coloquei. E talvez fosse o caso de por o JNat. Vi a resposta do JNat depois de ter feito.

Comment: @Maniero Sim, mas o sistema obriga por uma das tags e achei que a "bug" faria mais sentido que "debate".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É um processo manual, e ninguém se lembrou de remover o utluiz daí quando ele deixou de ser moderador.

E na verdade, não é preciso adicionar o Bacco à lista — o facto de ele ter o "diamante" faz com que ele tenha todos os privilégios necessários para moderar o chat. Pode-se adicionar... por uma questão de consistência — mas, não sendo necessário, defiro a decisão aos moderadores.